# cellForRowAtIndexPath equivalent function for section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to dynamically change an image in my tableview custom section header cell once the image finished being downloaded. However I do not how to get the reference to the section header cell. Is there an equivalent function for getting the header cell like there is for getting the table view cell using the function cellForRowAtIndexPath?

I tried but this is for the row. I need an equivalent for section header

```
if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? ListingTableViewCell {
    cellToUpdate.imageView.image = image!
}
```

Comment: That is not how you are supposed to change the displayed data, when the collectionView decides to reload its data this change will be lost. Use `reloadData` or `reloadSections(_:)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set tags for section header view.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
UIView *view = [UIView new];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
view.tag = section;

return view;
}
```

Then use tag to get the section header view.

```
 NSInteger section2 = 2;
 UIView *sectionHeader = [self.tableView viewWithTag:section2];
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize your headers, you can override the following method from the `UITableViewDataSource`.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

It works pretty much `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You juste have to create your view and return it. Here is an example to set a `UIImage` as header of section 0 :

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];

            return imageView;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return [[UIView alloc] init];
}
```